# in python, what should I add to fetch URLs form my (text file) or my (xml file) which include list of URLs?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, io

I have this code which is all work fine with (one link )
Result of the code store values (availableOffers,otherpricess,currentprice,page_url) in (prices.csv) file

my problems are : **First** : I do not know what to write to fetch URLs form my (text file) or my (xml file) instead of one URL in this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  

page_url = "XXXXXXXXX"


uClient = uReq(page_url)
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()


availableOffers = page_soup.find("input", {"id": "availableOffers"})["value"]
otherpricess = page_soup.find("span", {"class": "price"}).text.replace("$", "")
currentprice = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "is"}).text.strip().replace("$", "")


out_filename = "prices.csv"
headers = "availableOffers,otherpricess,currentprice,page_url \n"

f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)


f.write(availableOffers + ", " + otherpricess + ", " + currentprice + ", " + page_url + "\n")

f.close()
```

**Second problem** : when URL do not have value for (otherpricess ) I get this error

```
line 13, in <module> 
otherpricess = page_soup.find("span", {"class": "price"}).text.replace("$", "")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

how I bypass this error and tell the code to work even there are a value missing

**thanks**

Comment: post the sample url's in the textfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch urls from text file, you can `open` a file (exactly as you did for write) in `"r"` mode, and iterate over it's line.

For example, lets say you have the following urls file, named *urls.txt*:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

In order to fetch the urls and iterate over them, do the following:

```
out_filename = "prices.csv"
headers = "availableOffers,otherpricess,currentprice,page_url \n"

with open(out_filename, "w") as fw:
    fw.write(headers)
    with open("urls.txt", "r") as fr:
        for url in map(lambda x: x.strip(), fr.readlines()):  # the strip is to remove the trailing '\n'
            print(url)
            uClient = uReq(url)
            page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
            # write the rest logic here
            # ...
            # write to the output file
            fw.write(availableOffers + ", " + otherpricess + ", " + currentprice + ", " + page_url + "\n")
```

Regarding your second question, you can check that `page_soup.find("span", {"class": "price"})` is not None and if so, extract the text. For example:

```
otherpricess = page_soup.find("span", {"class": "price"}).text.replace("$", "") if page_soup.find("span", {"class": "price"}) else "" 
# in case there is no value, otherpricess will be empty string but you can change it to any other value.
```

Comment: for second part , I get this new error line 24, in <module>
    f.write(availableOffers + ", " + otherpricess + ", " + currentprice + ", " +
 page_url + "\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: @user2653711 I've updated my solution, try now please

Comment: yes seem to work but the result in (prices.csv) have only 1 Row of values and it seem the result for last URL only, it seem it write value of first url , then replace it next value of second url , then replace it with value of last url

Comment: It depends on yours implementation. I guess that the problem occurs because you open and close the file to write (`open(out_filename, "w")`) inside the loop that iterates over the urls. I would suggest you to open the output file to write and write the headers before starting the url iteration and inside the loop only write the data (`f.write(availableOffers + ", " + otherpricess + ", " + currentprice + ", " + page_url + "\n")`). In that case, you will have all the urls data and not only the last.

Comment: @user2653711 I've updated the code with example for how it should be implemented

Comment: @user2653711 I posted it in my solution, please check it out.

Comment: line 26, in <module>
    fw.write(availableOffers + ", " + otherpricess + ", " + currentprice + ", "
+ page_url + "\n")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Please make sure that you're following my instructions. I've tested this solution and it works well. For debugging purposes, copy my snippet and replace `fw.write(availableOffers + ", " + otherpricess + ", " + currentprice + ", " + page_url + "\n")` with `fw.write(url+"\n")`. It will produce output files with urls. Then, add your logic and debug it.

Comment: line 26, in <module>
    fw.write(url + "\n")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Do you have `close()` inside the loop? if so, please remove it.

Comment: no I do not you have close() any where,,, code almost finished accept this point

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of ideas. Need to see your code. I tested my code and if you use exactly this code, it should work. The only thing I can think about is that you write to the output file outside the `with open(out_filename, "w") as fw` block. If not, you will have to share your code.

Comment: You have no indentations. It should be: https://repl.it/repls/UnawareFullRatios